# Docker continues using ruby version 2.7.5 even though dockerfile specifies 2.7.7

Tags: ruby, docker

When I run:
`docker compose up`
I keep getting this error:
`Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 2.7.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.7`

Nowhere in the codebase is 2.7.5 written. The gemfile, .ruby-version, dockerfile all say 2.7.7. Should I be specifying the ruby version when running the docker command?

One line above in the error trace is:
`bundler: failed to load command: rails (/usr/local/bundle/bin/rails)`.

I have recently switched from rbenv to asdf, and am wondering if I've interfered with some ruby version manager config.

Comment: Can you share the files? I'd guess you're starting from  a specific image (say "ubuntu") that already has aruby 2.7.5, and then - after you install your preferred version - the system still sees the old one as default?

Comment: Why are you using docker and rbenv? What does your `.ruby-version` file and and you `Dockerfile` specify?

Answer (score 0):

`docker compose up` does not always replace already created containers. If your compose file builds the images you can try to run `docker compose up --build`